# Does "$X$ is independent with $Y$" implies "$\mathbb{E}[X|Z]$ is independent with $Y$"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

Suppose two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Does this imply that for any random variable $Z$, $\mathbb{E}[X|Z]$ is independent with $Y$?

The above seems very intuitive to me, but I feel it's hard to prove rigorously using the definitions...

---

Answered (which is No) by @AlexL in the comments (thanks AlexL!).

Comment: My probability is very rusty, but what about $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y]$ (say $X$ and $Y$ real) ? Is it independant with $Y$ ?

Comment: @AlexL Thanks so much! Your comment really hits the point. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent results of fair coin tosses. You are really giving a counter-example. By symmetry, $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \frac{X+Y}{2}$.

Comment: The result would be true if $Z$ were assumed to be independent of $\sigma(X,Y)$.